# fitnesse: howto load a symbol with a result in query table

Tags: fitnesse

In a FitNesse query table, is it possible to load a symbol with the returned results?

example of what I would like to do:

```
|Query: GetPlayers|
| name  | age | ID    |
| jones | 36  | $ID1= |
| smith | 27  | $ID2= |
```

Or alternatively, just have one $ID symbol which is loaded with a collection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe this is still an unresolved issue in FitNesse.  There is a PivotalTracker entry for it, that no one has take one yet: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/1893214.  I've looked at it, but haven't been able to solve it myself.

We currently work around this by having a driver that can do equivalent query.  Then we get the value back from the query.  It is much more cumbersome, but works for now.

I completely agree that this should be possible.  But as far as I know, it has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I wasn't aware of the issue tracking system for FitNesse. This issue is an exact match of what I want to do - guess I'll have to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your problem, but this is working fine for me:

```
|Query: whatever|whatever_param |
|key            |value          |
|a_key          |$symbol=       |
|check          |$symbol|a_value|
```

I use Cslim, and the method `whatever.query()` returns a list of maps that correspond to the keys (the key `a_key` have the value `a_value` for this exemple)